# Erro no formulário PHP recebo o formulário sem as informações

Tags: php

Eu recebo o email porém, eu não recebo as informações. Preciso de ajuda.

```
<div class="formArea row m0">


    <form action="contact_process.php" class="row m0 contact_form" id="contactForm">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row m0">
                <label for="contact_name">Name <span>*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_name" id="contact_name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="row m0">
                <label for="contact_phone">Phone</label>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="contact_phone" id="contact_phone">
            </div>
            <div class="row m0">
                <label for="monthly_badget">Monthly Budget</label>
                <select name="monthly_badget" id="monthly_badget" class="selectpicker form-control">
                    <option value="0" disabled selected>-(Monthly Budget)-</option>
                    <option value="200">200 USD</option>
                    <option value="300">300 USD</option>
                    <option value="400">400 USD</option>
                    <option value="500">500 USD</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row m0">
                <label for="contact_email">Email <span>*</span></label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="contact_email" id="contact_email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="row m0">
                <label for="contact_url">Website <span>*</span></label>
                <input type="url" class="form-control" name="contact_url" id="contact_url" required>
            </div>
            <div class="row m0">
                <label for="learn_seowave">How did you learn about SEOWAVE</label>
                <select name="learn_seowave" id="learn_seowave" class="selectpicker form-control">
                    <option value="0" disabled selected>-(Select)-</option>
                    <option value="google">Google Search</option>
                    <option value="yahoo">Yahoo Search</option>
                    <option value="blog">Blog</option>
                    <option value="forum">Forum</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row m0">
                <label for="interested_in">Which services are you interested in?</label>
                <select name="interested_in" id="interested_in" class="selectpicker form-control">
                    <option value="off_page">Off Page Optimization</option>
                    <option value="on_page">On Page Optimization</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row m0">
                <label for="addInfos">Additional Information</label>
                <textarea name="addInfos" id="addInfos" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <button class="borderred_link" type="submit"><span>submit details!</span></button>
        </div>                            
    </form>
```

O PHP

```
<?php

    $to = " contato@agenciahabitat.com.br ";
    $from = $_REQUEST['contact_email'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['contact_name'];
    $headers = "From: $from";
    $subject = "Você tem  mensagem do seu formulário";

    $fields = array();
    $fields{"name"} = 'contact_name';
    $fields{"email"} = 'contact_email';
    $fields{"url"} = 'contact_url';
    $fields{"phone"} = 'contact_phone';
    $fields{"Monthly Budget"} = "monthly_badget";
    $fields{"How know about SEOWAVE"} = "learn_seowave";
    $fields{"Interested In"} = "interested_in";
    $fields{"Additional Information"} = "addInfos";

    $body = " Aqui está o que foi enviado:\n\n "; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Você não recebe mais nenhum campo?

Comment: recebo asssim: Aqui está o que foi enviado:

contact_name: 
contact_email: 
contact_url: 
contact_phone: 
monthly_badget: 
learn_seowave: 
interested_in: 
addInfos:

Comment: Dê um print_r($_REQUEST) e ve se os nomes dos campos estão sendo enviados para a requisição. Se não estiver, tente nomear o formulario e coloque o metodo de envio de get ou post  "<form  method="post">.

Answer (score 0):

No formulário alterne o método para `POST`:

```
<?php
mail("contato@agenciahabitat.com.br,tmkt1494@uol.com.br,email3@gmail.com,email4@outlook.com,email5@yahoo.com.br","Assunto","Corpo");
?>
```

Há cada virgula coloque um endereço de E-Mail diferente, sendo de diferentes provedores, coloque no 3 um gmail, no 4 um outlook/hotmail, etc, preencha com todos os e-mails possíveis sendo cada um de um provedor diferente, verifique em todos a caixa de entrada e a caixa de SPAM (mais plausivel), se pelo menos um deles receber o e-mail o probleman não é no seu provedor e sim no no serviço de email.

Se nenhum receber e não puder trocar de hospedagem terá que usar o **PHPMailer** para autenticação (sendo obrigatório as configurações SMTP fornecidos pelo suporte da hospedagem), e se nem isso der certo mas você não tiver como trocar a hospedagem no momento eu vou passar uma instrução de como usar um serviço de terceiros gratuito pra enviar o email com ou sem uso de AJAX (javascript) para que o usuário não veja o endereço do serviço dando a impressão de que o formulário enviou pelo seu site.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73574/discussion-on-answer-by-rpgboss-erro-no-formulario-php-recebo-o-formulario-sem-a)

Comment: Desisto, nada funciona.

Comment: Estou aguardando no CHAT